# CSS: How to have a button background image of the same size as the button?

Tags: html, css, button, background-image

I read this link, and unfortunately, it didn't help me:
[How to make background image shrink proportionally to fit button size in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9507774/how-to-make-background-image-shrink-proportionally-to-fit-button-size-in-javascr)

I want to generate a button, whose background will be an image. I want CSS to match the image size to be as big as the button is.

This is the CSS I wrote:

```
button {
    border: solid;
    background-image: url("../img/download.png");
    background-size: 100%;
}
```

I don't know why, but I don't see any image in the button background. Do you know how to help me?

Comment: Add a fiddle so we can see where you went wrong.

Answer (score 4):

Try `background-size: cover;`, if I'm understanding what you. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to use an anchor tag instead of a button, and make it act as a button. The other thing you can do it wrap the button outside a span and set the span to the same size as the button in regards.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you use `background-size` it will take the whole button size and work perfectly, but in your specific case I think you have some other stylesheet that overrides your button style.

**Note:**

Avoid using style with HTML tags in this case `button` it will affect all buttons style in the page. Either give it a specific `id` or `class` and use your style with it.

This may be the problem in your case, you are using the style with `button` and maybe there's another stylesheet that overrides it.

**Demo:**

This is a working snippet showing that `background-siz:100%;e` works perfectly :

```css
button.customBtn {
  border: solid;
  background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/uRBtadp.jpg");
  background-size: 100%;
}
```

```html
<button class="customBtn">Click me!</button>
```